# Check if a value exists in a column for each id Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have data like this

[image]

and I want output like this

[image]

I want to have a column Has_Rose to say if Rose is there in Category column for each id.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create new column to indicate if it has rose value. use 0,1 to indicate the presence
2. group by id and sum the new column
3. Create resulting dataset converting 0 to 'No', else to 'yes'(sum > 0 suggests there is at least one Rose in id group)

Solution could be similar to this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

df = df.withColumn(
    'has_rose',
    func.when(func.col('category') == "Rose", 1).otherwise(0))
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(func.sum('has_rose').alias('num_roses'))
df = df.select(
    'id',
    func.when(func.col('num_roses') = '0', 'no').otherwise('yes').alias('has_rose')
)
df.show()
```